# Why does having many Print statements slow down my code?

Tags: performance-tuning, debugging, user-interface

I have a code that I need to debug. I have put a `Print[]` into it that should give about 10^4 prints for table entries. 
I know that 10^4 is large, and this exposes the fact that it takes more and more as the number of outputs gets large ... Can anybody explain the reason why it gets so slow as the number of `Print[]` statements grows?

Comment: How about replacing all instances of `Print[]` with `Sow[]` and enclose the entire beast in `Reap[]`? You can then study the list thus produced at leisure.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. But usually you do want to see the output of Print during execution time, and often not just the current one (then of course a simple Dynamic[printoutput] would be enough.

Comment: Okay; does `PrintTemporary[]` also incur a speed penalty when used?

Comment: @Rolf You'd want to see 10^4 `Print[]` instances in real time during execution? If the volume of log entries is enough that it clogs up the Front End, you almost certainly don't want to examine them visually. `Sow[]` or file-based solutions like yours will get that data where you need it, in a machine-readable form which is likely more useful, without you needing to actually see it.

Comment: @episanty Quiero ver todo!

Comment: @RolfMertig In which case, the programming gods demand a performance-hit sacrifice to be made, in proportion to the size of the todo that you want to see ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to why I do not know. Maybe the `FrontEnd` is too inefficient in creating thousands of output cells. 
Maybe people do not do this and use `WriteString` instead.
E.g. this evaluates in 0.6 seconds on my machine

```
$startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
    Do[mybigfun[i]; WriteString["stdout", " \n", {i, Date[]}], {i, 10^4}];
    AbsoluteTime[] - $startTime
```

while this

```
$startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
    Do[mybigfun[i]; Print[{i, Date[]}], {i, 10^4}];
    AbsoluteTime[] - $startTime
```

needs 63 seconds.

And yes, I also think that the overhead of the standard notebook `FrontEnd` is too much. You could use Wolfram Workbench then, once it will be released to the general public for Mathematica 10. Or you use the Text-based interface until then.

Comment: Dear Rolf, thanks a lot for this tip. The `WriteString` thing takes 1.6 seconds here, the `Print` one has stuck my laptop and has been going on for minutes now, as it did before in my actual program. Thanks a lot for your comment and for helping out!

Comment: Dear Roberto: Prego. I get very very annoyed by some FrontEnd inefficiencies, but often there is a way around such trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but I've had this experience as well with multiple programming languages.

Generally a program executes lines sequentially. Simple arithmetic operations take place almost entirely on the CPU / Cache, and are very fast. However, Print[] communicates with other parts of the software and may need to wait for them.

I/O tends to be a limiting factor in lots of applications.

Comment: This is a user interface thingy ...